# Is possible to add context's/labels at changelog level in liquibase?

Tags: database, liquibase

Is possible to add context's/labels at changelog level in liquibase?

Here is the  scenario:
    can i specify a context in a change-log file to apply for the multiple includes, see example below. In my case , a master change-log file includes this sub-change-log-file , so that i can have multiple change logs with different contexts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">

 <include file="my_table.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
 <include file="my_view.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
 <include file="my_functions.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the feature has been implemented in 3.5.0, details here: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-155

You can either have it at master changelog file by doing:

`<include file="changelog-included.xml" context="d and e"/>`

Or, have it at child changelog file, by doing:

`<databaseChangeLog ... context="a and (b or c)">`

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported.